# Eval() vs. Expression Tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am in the process of designing a survey system for our clients to report data to the central office.  Which questions are asked in which cases is a complicated problem, and needs to be customizable without changing code.  I'm thinking along the following lines:

**Model**

```
Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :conditional_statement
  has_and_belongs_to_many :named_conditionals
end

NamedConditional < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :questions

  def evaluate
    # return true or false, depending on which conditional and the state of the system
  end
end
```

The idea being here that a `NamedConditional` can perform a test on the state of the system, and return a boolean.  These named conditionals can then be referenced by name in `conditional_statement` in `Question`, using many `NamedConditionals` and logical operatiors. Then the flow for determining if a given question should be asked will go something like this:

1. Find all dependent `NamedCondtionals`
2. Evaluate all dependent `NamedConditionals`
3. Use the value of each `NamedConditional` to evaluate `conditional_statement` in `Question`

My question is in step 3, how expensive will it be to use `eval()` to do the evaluation of conditional_statement?  I see the other option as parsing `conditional_statement` into a expression tree when `Question` is saved, storing that in the database (serialized), and then deserializing it when I need to evaluate it.

There could be many (100+) questions that this needs to happen for a given request.  Obviously I can cache and reuse the values of each `NamedConditional` (because each one will be used for multiple questions).  Is there a point where eval() will perform better than an expression tree in this case?  Or are both options garbage?

Comment: Why not knock out a proof-of-concept with both methods, and benchmark it at 100k or 1M iterations?

Comment: Ya, I've been playing around with it.  Cannot really determine best case yet; needs some more tweaking.  I'll post results, when I can get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gut feel is that the expression tree serialisation/deserialisation will take much longer than just evalling some conditionals.

After all - the conditions are evalled at the speed of ruby - plus a small constant for interpreting the string. serialisation/deserialisation is slow - and will increase at the very least polynomially as N increases... probably more than that.

Comment: Ya, the testing i have done tends to back this up.  The expensive part for my use case is substituting values into the expression.  I ended up parsing the expression on save, replacing named values by a hash lookup.  So "foo && bar" gets saved as "values[:foo] && values[:bar]", then i just populate the values hash before eval.  Turned out waaaay cheaper than the expression tree.